# How Can I change default priority of constraints in Xcode 6?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, autolayout, constraints

I am using Autolayout on Storyboard and when I add constraints, their priorities are allways set to 1000 by default.

After putting many constraints, I want one to be higher than the others. But since they are all 1000 and I cannot set it greater than 1000, I have to change all other constraints less than 1000.

Can I change the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the default behavior for what priority a new constraint has when you create it, but you can easily change priority of the existing constraints. Double-click a constraint in the canvas or in the attributes inspector and you'll get a little popup where you can change it.